# Getting the latest pair value with Kraken API

Tags: c#, trading, kraken.com

I am trying to get the latest value/rate for a given pair using the Kraken API, but I cannot really figure  it out.
Is there anyone that knows how to do it?

I am using the C# code provided on Git (https://github.com/trenki2/KrakenApi) and thought using the following function was the way to go:

```
client.GetRecentTrades("XETHZEUR",ID)
```

I however don't want to use an ID, which seems to be optional according to Kraken Website.
I just want to know what is the current value, nothing more.

I have also used GetTicker to get the last trade, but this does not come with a Time stamp and will not give the actual currency pair value.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `GetTicker` and `GetRecentTrades` will give you the value of the last trade. You can use either depending on what other data you need. I guess there could be some difference because most likely Kraken caches the results.

Of the two methods above only `GetRecentTrades` will provide a timestamp.

Alternatively instead of getting the last trade you can call `GetOrderBook` and calculate the average between the lowest Ask price and highest Bid price.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you get the timestamp of the latest trade though?
Also, latest trade does not mean "pair value". Is there a way to get that?
I guess I could take the mean between latest sale and purchase.

Comment: @progLearner I've expanded on my answer. I think you need to decide what "pair value" means to you because to most people that's the last trade.

Comment: Thanks again. By "pair value", I mean the actual rate at a time t.
I guess taking the mean between min and max should be close enough, although there is no guaranty of either order to go through, but that should do as an estimate.